# How to play a video using video 5.12 qt qml?

Tags: qt, c++11, qml

I want to play a video with the button of play, pause,  forward the video in 10 seconds, and back the video using qml, but I don't know how.

something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import QtMultimedia 5.12

import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 840
    height: 680
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout{
        Video {
            id: video
            width : 600
            height : 600
            source: "a.avi"

        }
        RowLayout{
            Button {
                width: 80
                height: 80
                text: "play"
                onClicked: {video.play()}
            }
            Button {
                width: 80
                height: 80
                text: "pause"
                onClicked: {video.pause()}
            }
            Button {
                width: 80
                height: 80
                text: "foward"
                onClicked: {video.foward()}
            }
            Button {
                width: 80
                height: 80
                text: "back"
                onClicked: {video.back()}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i dont know format the text very well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is the [source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-video.html#source-prop). You need to use an URL format:
`source: "file:///home/user/videos/a.avi"`

Alternatively, you can embed the video in the executable using the QtResources file (`.qrc`).

Comment: How can I forward the video, like I currently in second 10 so I click in the forward button and I go to the second 20, How can I do that?

Comment: Firstly if the answer solves your issue mark it as accepted. 
Secondly, to move back and forward you need to use the [seek()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-video.html#seek-method)